# Use pre-signed url to get objects

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the objects in AWS S3 by listObjects but I need to do this with a pre-signed url.
The following code gives me the objects:

```
$objects = $s3Client->listObjects([
   'Bucket' => $bucket,
   'Prefix' => $prefix
]);
```

The problem is that I need to do it with a presigned url. I get the url with following:

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('ListObjects', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Prefix' => $prefix
]);
$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
$url = (string)$request->getUri();
```

And I retrieve the objects when accessing the URL through the browser but I need to get objects in PHP instead of a link to them. How do I do that?

Comment: Download the URL the way you would any other, e.g. `file_get_contents` or curl.

Comment: How is that the right way, if I can get the objects with $s3Client->execute($cmd)? Isn't there a similar like execute($request)?

Answer (score -1):

```
$s3Client = Aws::createClient('s3');
$result = $s3Client->getObject(array(
   'Bucket' => $bucket,
   'Key'    => $path
));
$metadata = $result->get("@metadata");
$statusCode = $metadata["statusCode"];
if ($statusCode == 200) {
    header("Content-type: text/image");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$path);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    return $result['Body'];//echo $result['Body'];
}
```